# changing the layout of current activity

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

```
FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

This gives me an error

```
error: cannot find symbol
    FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                                          ^
symbol:   method findViewById(int)
```

I have already imported the required R package

Comment: Are you extending `Activity`?

Comment: please post your complete activity and xml layout

Comment: I am not extending activity

Comment: i was trying to find a way to change the current layout without changing activity

Comment: `findViewById` is a method of either `View` or `Activity`. You have to call the method on an object of one of those two types.

Comment: @Yjay Please give an example in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to access the layout of your current `Activity` from a different class. Instead of trying to find your `FrameLayout` in the different class, save the reference to the `FrameLayout` inside of your `Activity`, and pass the `FrameLayout` to your seperate class (the class where you are currently seeing this issue).

E.g.

Activity Class:

```
...
OtherObject myOtherObject = new OtherObject();
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_frame_layout);
myOtherObject.doStuffWithFrameLayout(frameLayout);
...
```

OtherObject Class:

```
...
public void doStuffWithFrameLayout(FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    //You can use the FrameLayout here and do stuff with it.

    //You will likely also want to pass in a Context object if you want to
    //create a LayoutInflater or do other Context-dependent stuff
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);

In case this does not work remove the import of yourPackage.R and hit the button 'fix imports' not sure the import you did is correct. I always get 2 different options.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `setContentView()` again, but keep in mind that **this will invalidate all of your View references**, so make sure that you initialize them again.

There's almost never a reason to do this, so I would suggest you look into using Fragments, and just swap out the Fragments instead.

Answer (score 0):

To use `android.R.id.content`, you must import android.R, not yourAppPackage.R .

And to use multiple layouts within one activity, you have to use ViewFlipper or ViewAnimator (or call setContentView multiple times, but it's resource expensive if you have huge layouts).